# When I dynamically add widgets on windows should I specify parent?

Tags: c++, qt, qtwidgets

Should I do:

```
auto btnDelete = new QPushButton(this);
btnDelete->setText("Delete");
```

or is it safe to do:

```
auto btnDelete = new QPushButton("Delete");
```

And why?

I add it with: `this->ui->formLayout->addRow(btnDelete, editForm);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is perfectly safe. The moment you add it to a layout, the layout will set the parent for you. To whatever widget is owner of layout. The moment the parent is deleted it will also call the deconstructer of your pushbutton